# Gap detector does not register high speed projectiles

Tags: arduino, speed, detector

I'm trying to build a gap detector-based ASG gun chrono. I successfully connected two gap detectors to Arduino Uno, wrote a program, which measures time between two voltage spikes (on each gap detector) and attached them to aluminium profile, such that ASG projectile must cross the IR streams of gap detectors (ASG projectile has 6mm diameter, the profile has around 8-9 mm of space inside, detector is positioned exactly at the center, vertically).

The setup looks like following (without the profile):

[image: Setup]

Now when I drop the projectile into that profile, Arduino correctly notices two spikes (from each detector) and measures time between them. But when I shoot the projectile from the slow spring-based ASG gun, nothing happens.

My suspicion is that the time, when projectile covers the IR stream is so short, that detector does not have enough time to raise the voltage and thus Arduino does not register any change.

Core part of the source code looks like following:

```
#include "Display.h"
#include "Keypad.h"
#include "Menu.h"
#include "EnableInterrupt.h"

// Global variables -----------------------------------------------------------

LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);
Display display(lcd, 16, 2);
Keypad keypad;

BaseMenuItem * mainItems[] = 
{
  new ActionMenuItem("\x01 Pomiar FPS", 1),
};

MainMenu mainMenu(display, mainItems, sizeof(mainItems) / sizeof(BaseMenuItem *));

// *** FPS measurement ***

unsigned long fpsStart;
unsigned long fpsEnd;
int fpsMode = 0;

// Global functions -----------------------------------------------------------

void detector1Up()
{
  fpsStart = micros();
  fpsMode = 1;

  disableInterrupt(A1);
  enableInterrupt(A2, detector2Up, RISING);  
}

void detector2Up()
{
  fpsEnd = micros();
  fpsMode = 2;
  disableInterrupt(A2);
}

void fpsDisplay(long ms)
{
  lcd.clear();

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("ms: ");
  lcd.print(ms);
}

void fpsDisplayMissedError()
{
  lcd.clear();

  lcd.print(" *** Error *** ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Missed 2 sensor");
}

void fpsMeasurement()
{
  fpsMode = 0;
  enableInterrupt(A1, detector1Up, RISING);

  fpsDisplay(0);

  bool finish = false;
  while (!finish)
  {
    if (fpsMode == 1)
    {
      // Checking if particle missed second sensor

      unsigned long now = micros();
      if (now > fpsStart && now - fpsStart > 1000000)
      {
        // If second passed after first measurement, assume, that
        // particle missed second sensor

        // Stop waiting for second sensor
        disableInterrupt(A2);

        fpsDisplayMissedError();

        // Restart measurement
        fpsMode = 0;
        enableInterrupt(A1, detector1Up, RISING);
      }
    }    

    if (fpsMode == 2)
    {
      // Checking if measurement was made

      if (fpsEnd > fpsStart)
      {
        unsigned long timeDist = fpsEnd - fpsStart;
        fpsDisplay(timeDist);

        Serial.print("Measured time: ");
        Serial.print(timeDist);
        Serial.print("\n");
      }

      fpsMode = 0;
      enableInterrupt(A1, detector1Up, RISING);
    }
    else
    {
      // Waiting for keypress - exiting mode

      int key = keypad.ReadKey();
      if (key != KEY_NONE)
        finish = true;
    }
  }

  disableInterrupt(A1);
  disableInterrupt(A2);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  // (...)

  delay(2000);
  mainMenu.Show();
}

void loop()
{
  int key = keypad.ReadKey();
  int result = mainMenu.Action(key);
  if (result == 1)
  {
    fpsMeasurement();
    mainMenu.Show();
  }
}
```

How may I improve either hardware or software to register the particle and thus be able to measure its speed?

---

**Edit:**

To avoid too big discussion in comments, I'll provide all requested information here:

@PlasmaHH: The gap detector uses (I guess) IR diode and IR detector on the other side. When attached to Arduino, it gives low voltage on no obstacle and high voltage on obstacle between diode and detector. I don't have values here, but from what I remember values were like 31-32 without obstacle and around 800 when obstacle was present (Arduino scales voltage 0~5V to 0~1023).

@JRE: Schematics of the detector are [on shop's page of the detector] (leaving link if more information is needed)[2](http://electropark.pl/moduly-optyczne/3291-modul-detektora-szczelinowego-10mm.html).

[image]

Close-up on the detector itself:

[image]

@OllinLanthrop: This is weird, Google Image Search on "Aluminium profile" returns exactly what I've used. But for clarity, I'm using the following piece of alluminium:

[image]

I drilled holes in two places in the profile, such that detector's beam goes exactly through the profile and the holes are centered vertically on the profile. I hope that image gives you more information on my build. Also, "dropping" projectile should have more sense now.

Also, a gun chrono (or chronograph) is a device, which measures speed of projectile. Commercial one looks like following:[image]

Comment: We have no idea what the hardware does and how it works, how should we suggest ways to improve it? Have you done any measurements about the signals when your projectile arrives?

Comment: What is the rating for performance of the detector? you may need to consider a better quality / performance ratio.

Comment: What does the circuit look like on the detectors?

Comment: check the specs for the gap detectors there is likely some debouncing going on to avoid specs of dust giving false readings

Comment: 400fps is around 120 meters per second. If the distance is 10cm between the detectors you need to run all your arduino sketch in 0.8 miliseconds or 800 microseconds. That's a lot to ask for an arduino ussually.  Have you tried reducing the problem, use only one sensor and see if you can trigger that? Maybe the sensors are not triggering or you can't read the distance between the two fast enough.

Comment: Way too much hand waving.  *"Gap detector-based ASG gun chrono"* isn't defined, but seems to be important.  Then there is *aluminum profile*.  Huh? What?  Some vague thing is centered vertically, but all I see is some stuff thrown on a table.  The picture is supposed to be without a *profile*, whatever that is.  *"Dropping"* a projectile makes no sense.  What a mess!  Closing as *unclear*.

Comment: While I agree with Olin, @Andrés, where is 800 µs "much to ask" from a properly programmed microcontroller ("properly programmed" as in "not this code")? The thing is – eyeballing this, no idea what hardware this is – running at ca 40 MHz, so that'd be 32000 cycles. In that time, doing a measurement should be possible. Problem is that you'd need to circumvent most of what the Arduino framework does for you to actually deal with the raw interrupts without significant latency.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I provided more information in the question.

Comment: @OlinLanthrop I provided more information in the question.

Comment: @JRE I provided more information in the question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller definitely possible with a microcontroller, 1ms is an eternity nowadays.. But arduino runs a whole lot of things in the background and is not intended for this type of things.

Comment: The answer from @peufeu explains why I asked for the circuit diagram of the detectors.

Comment: Yes, your hunch was correct, it seems!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the detector schematic, I see a 10k pullup on the phototransistor, and a "104" (100nF) capacitor to ground, to filter noise.

**The time constant of this RC filter is much too slow to detect a flying projectile.**

Simple solution: desolder the capacitor ! If it still does not pulse, use a lower pullup like 1k for extra speed, and increase LED current accordingly.

The detector datasheet should mention its speed and max currents.

Code-wise, you should really use pin-change interrupts which will be both simpler and a lot more accurate. All you have to do is:

- When "detector 1" sees projectile, grab value from timer and store into a variable
- When "detector 2" sees projectile, grab value from timer and substract previously stored value.

You can use "micros()" instead of a timer if you're real lazy.

**EDIT**

The docs for micros():

> Returns the number of microseconds since the Arduino board began running the current program. This number will overflow (go back to zero), after approximately 70 minutes. On 16 MHz Arduino boards (e.g. Duemilanove and Nano), this function has a resolution of four microseconds (i.e. the value returned is always a multiple of four). On 8 MHz Arduino boards (e.g. the LilyPad), this function has a resolution of eight microseconds.

I guess your UNO runs @ 16 Mhz. So 800µs is 12800 cycles, which is plenty.

If you use a proper timer clocked at 16 Mhz, you'll get excellent precision.

If you use micros() with its idiotic rounding down to 4 clocks, you'll get 4x worse precision, but still okay.

The important thing is to avoid interrupt jitter and other sources of jitter. So, if you do everything in software using a pin change interrupt, you must ensure no other higher priority interrupt can block it (like arduino timers, serial or whatnot) and of course don't do anything that can take a variable amount of time in your interrupt.

Now, the usual way to do this is to use a timer in capture mode. The hardware will trigger on the pin you specify and capture the value of the running timer into a register, THEN it will raise an interrupt which can read the captured value. In this case, since the value has been captured at the highest precision by hardware, it does not matter if the interrupt that will read it has jitter. There is an example [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8782/how-to-use-timer1-at328mega-to-measure-the-time-between-rising-edges-of-two-in).

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to post a schematic of your project along with actual part numbers.

In reviewing your sketch, you are unnecessarily enabling and disabling interrupts. Any latency in your program could cause it to miss an event as a result.

My recommendation is that you simply enable interrupts, leave them enabled, and use your state machine to determine the detection status.

Also ensure that any wait loops in the main code that are monitoring the state machine do not tie up processor resources.

Ideally this should be implemented with hardware timers since a simple fetch of micros(), for example, can call dozens of lines of assembly code, thereby introducing significant latency during an interrupt. Remember that the ASG velocity can easily be 400 fps. If your sensors are one foot apart, this gives you less than 2.5 milliseconds to process an interrupt.

If you suspect that the detector is not catching the ASG projectile flight, simply create a test program with one detector that reports if/when the interrupt has occurred.

Edit:

In looking at the schematic for the PE that you added to your question, I would recommend removing the capacitor that is between the minus input and ground. The cap will slow down the response of the PE which is the opposite of what you need.

Comment: nah, his microcontroller probably even has a timer unit that you can trigger with external interrupts. It's just that Arduino is about as far as you can get from meddling with timers while still working on a microcontroller.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Arduino makes microcontroller programming easier by abstracting away details of the hardware. Sadly, that implies hiding a few nontrivially usable features, like using one of the features of the timer units that are typically only useful for more advanced applications

Comment: @MarcusMüller I guess the only option to gain access to such features is to write code in microcontroller's assembler or directly in machine code? Or use the microcontroller alone?

Comment: I don't know Arduino well enough to tell you whether it's possible to use such features and the Arduino software stack together. In any case, microcontrollers are usually programmed in C, not assembler, these days, unless absolutely necessary (which is most definitely not the case here). You'd typically just write a firmware from scratch that does exactly what you need and not more. That will be more complicated than using the Arduino libs (e.g. for talking to a display), but it will allow you to use every feature in the microcontroller's datasheet :)